# Filter foreach array based on value inside this array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I have the following array:

`$tourcontent`

[image]

and the following foreach:

```
foreach($tourcontent as $set)
```

How I can limit the result of the output of this foreach to be limited to only where in the sub array `categories[]` contains value of 5 where `$tourcontent[]['info']['categories'][] = 5 ?`

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you please give an example of the output you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `in_array`.

```
foreach($tourcontent as $set) {
    if (in_array(5, $set['info']['categories'])) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

This will only "do stuff" to the `$set`s that contain `5` in their `['info']['categories']` arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe if you don't need to foreach all the array, you could try something like:

```
foreach($tourcontent['info']['categories'] as $category)
{
  if($category == 5)
  {
    echo "found!"
  }  
}
```

Comment: If you look at the example `$tourcontent[]['info']` that won't work.